# blend shape doesn't work correctly

Tags: shape-keys

I'm trying to blend the duck object into a whale model. Both were made from a subdivided cube model with no extrusions or modifiers. I did use a mirror modifier when creating the whale model but didn't use one for the duck model. I did apply the modifier before using the blend shape tool however, so it should work since they were both made from the same base model? They were both made in different scene/files if that might be of an issue. I don't think it should be an issue but I'm not sure what the problem is so any advice would be helpful!

[image]

Comment: Was the modifier applied on the original before making a new shape? Otherwise, you effectively do not have the same mesh. The vertex IDs were changed.

Comment: What do you mean by "blend shape tool"? What exactly is your workflow? I don't think Blender comes with any morphing tool by default, you can't just pick two meshes and ask Blender to morph (nicely) between them.